# Setting DNS suffix for multiple network adapters in a VM

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, domain

Is there a way to set the DNS Suffix for multiple network adapters in a VM using the sysprep file?

We are trying to setup Windows 2003 VMs with 2 network adapters. In the one adapter case the sysprep we are able to set the suffix using DNSDomain. But this doesnt work in the 2 adapter case. The The VM is setup  corrently though without any issues but one of our apps relies on the DNS Suffix value to work correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Write up a small vbscript that sets the dns suffix for all the adapters to the values you want, and add the script to the sysprep process.